# React Native SVG: fullscreen adaptive viewBox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I'm trying to make fullscreen scene with "react-native-svg" library.
That's my component render code:

```
<Svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100%">
    <Rect
        x="25"
        y="25"
        width="50"
        height="50"
        stroke="red"
        strokeWidth="2"
        fill="yellow"
    />
</Svg>
```

That's what I'm wanna to get:
[image]

But what I'm have in a landscape mode:

[image]

And the most important thing. the block is normalized when the resize event occurs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by

```
    const viewBox = '0 0 '+this.state.screenWidth+' '+this.state.screenHeight;
    return <Svg viewBox={viewBox} style={styles.wrapper}>
```

I think itsn't the best solution, but it's work